# React-select isMulti select all filtered options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I need to add "Select All" option in my multi-select. It should be displayed if there is at least 1 filtered option. Click on "Select All" should then add only filtered options (not all options necessarily) **to already selected options**.

1. Input is empty, so all options are "filtered":
   [image]

Clicking on Select All option would then add all options to selected options.

2. Input contains "custom", so only one option remains::
   [image]

Clicking on Select All option would then add only that one option to selected options.

It was easy to add "Select all" option that adds all initial options, but that isn't the solution to my problem. I managed to partially solve my problem by manually filtering options and storing them filtered in component's state, but I hope there is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a combination of `filterOption`, `InputChange` and `onChange` props:

- In `InputChange`you will catch the `inputValue` every time the user changes it and store it into the state. This value will be reused in `onChange`.
- You need to change the initial `filterOption` to display your `Select all` all the time. Original logic is if `inputValue` is `null` returns `true` else returns `true` is `inputValue` is included in option label or value. Before doing this logic, we had an other condition where if option value corresponds to your `Select all` option then returns `true` right away.
- In `onChange`; by default the returned options are those received. Then if an option has been selected (as it's multiple it could be removed) and this option is `Select all`, your returned value should be a copy of all the options and filter them by the `inputValue`.

Maybe there's a simplest way to do it but I think this one it pretty effective:

```
onChange = (opt, { option }) => {
  let newOpts = opt;
  let string = this.state.searchField;

  if (option && option.value === "all") {
    let filteredOptions = clone(options);

    filteredOptions = filteredOptions.filter(
      filteredOption =>
        isIncludingString(string, filteredOption) &&
        !newOpts.includes(filteredOption)
    );

    string = null;
    newOpts = newOpts
      .concat(filteredOptions)
      .filter(newOpt => newOpt.value !== "all");
  }
  this.setState({
    searchField: string,
    values: newOpts
  });
};

onInputChange = (string, { action }) => {
  if (action === "input-change") {
    this.setState({
      searchField: string
    });
  }
};  

filterOption = ({ label, value }, string) => {
  if (value === "all") {
    return true;
  } else if (string) {
    return label.includes(string) || value.toString().includes(string);
  } else {
    return true;
  }
};
```

> Important note, in my example I use `clone` from `lodash`

Below the `isIncludingString` function used in `onChange`.

```
function isIncludingString(string, option) {
  let result = false;
  if (
    !string ||
    option.label.toString().includes(string) ||
    option.value.toString().includes(string)
  ) {
    result = true;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-57698868-w706k).

Comment: Hey Laura, thank you for your answer. I solved it in a similar way. There is a bug if you for example want to "Select All" values that contains "3" and after that add values that contains "4" previous values get overwritten. I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I fixed it all. Changed a couple of things in onChange function :)  Thanks for your help!

Comment: For the "issue" you are talking about it's more another constraint ;) you can update your question, I'll change my code to suit this new requirement and maybe help other people.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the function that I used to convert all my existing multi selecters:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactSelect from "react-select";

const addSelectAllOptionIfIsMulti = (props) => {
  if (!props.isMulti) {
    return props;
  }
  const selectAllOption = {}; // just an object to be compared to by reference

  const getOptionLabel = (obj) =>
    obj === selectAllOption
      ? "Select all"
      : props.getOptionLabel
      ? props.getOptionLabel(obj)
      : obj.label;

  const getOptionValue = (obj) =>
    obj === selectAllOption
      ? selectAllOption
      : props.getOptionValue
      ? props.getOptionValue(obj)
      : obj.value;

  const onChange = (values) => {
    const selectedOptions = values.includes(selectAllOption)
      ? props.options
      : values;
    props.onChange(selectedOptions);
  };

  const options =
    props.options.length === props.value?.length
      ? props.options
      : [selectAllOption, ...props.options];

  return { ...props, getOptionLabel, getOptionValue, onChange, options };
};

function Select({...props}){
  return <ReactSelect {...addSelectAllOptionIfIsMulti(props)}/>
}
export default Select;
```