# How to get filtered options in MenuList?

Tags: react-select

I'm trying to build an "Insert all" into a custom `MenuList` component for `react-select`.

Looks like this:

```
const MySelect = (props) => {

  const MenuList = ({ children, ...ownProps }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => ownProps.setValue(props.options)}>
          Insert all
        </button>
        <components.MenuList {...ownProps}>{children}</components.MenuList>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <ReactSelect options={props.options} components={{ MenuList }} ... />
  );
}
```

The problem: `options` simply contains all options, before the user starts to type into the searchable select.

After starting to type, let's say 5 out of 50 options remain.

When someone clicks `Insert all`, I want to insert only the 5 remaining options. But all 50 options get inserted. I checked `ownProps` for something like `filteredOptions`, but that didn't exist. Is there any way to get the filtered options?

Comment: is `components.MenuList` simply rendering a list of items?

Comment: Yes, "enhanced" with a button on top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-select isMulti select all filtered options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57698868/react-select-ismulti-select-all-filtered-options)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `react-select` doesn't provide this sort of information. You have to achieve that by your own. Try to write a filterable state upon the `react-select` library.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work, but that's far from ideal :-/

```
...
  onClick={() => {
    const visibleOptions = props.options.filter(
      optionContainsStr(ownProps.selectProps.inputValue)
    );

    ownProps.setValue(visibleOptions);
  }}
...
```

```
const optionContainsStr = str => option => {
  return (
    option.value
      .toString()
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(str) || 
    option.label
      .toLowerCase()
      .includes(str)
  );
};
```

Comment: You obviously are doing something wrong. Cause this kind of simple functionality can be implemented much more simpler than the way you did it.